# nonce in digest authentication process

Tags: java, digest-authentication

I would like to know the usage of **nonce** in digest authentication and example of it. Here is my authentication method.

```
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URL urlObj;
        try {
            urlObj = new URL(url);

            HttpHost host = new HttpHost(urlObj.getHost(), urlObj.getPort(), urlObj.getProtocol());
            HttpGet job = new HttpGet(url);

            digestAuth.overrideParamter("realm", realm);
            digestAuth.overrideParamter("nonce", nonce);

            authCache.put(host, digestAuth);


            localcontext.setAttribute(ClientContext.AUTH_CACHE, authCache);

            HttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(job);
            StatusLine status = response2.getStatusLine();

            if(status.getStatusCode() == 401) {
                httpclient.close();
                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                Header header = response2.getFirstHeader(AUTH.WWW_AUTH);
                Map<String, String> map = parseAuthResponse(header);

                realm = map.get("realm");
                nonce = map.get("nonce");

                digestAuth.overrideParamter("realm", realm);

                digestAuth.overrideParamter("nonce", nonce);

                authCache.put(host, digestAuth);

                localcontext.setAttribute(ClientContext.AUTH_CACHE, authCache);

                httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                                            new AuthScope(urlObj.getHost(), AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
                                            new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));
                response2 = httpclient.execute(job);

            }
```

In the main method,

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            digestAuth = new DigestScheme();
            authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
            localcontext = new BasicHttpContext();

            download("url1");
            download("url2");
        }
```

I would like to skip authentication for the second download by the **nonce**. Is that possible?
In my understanding, the wiki says that I can reuse the **nonce** for next request. I would like to know the right usage of **nonce**. Can I use like this?

Answer (score 1):

A nonce is a Number used ONCE and therefore should only be used once to prevent different kind of attacks.

The server sets the nonce, not you, so the right usage is not to set it.

As the [HttpClient documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/authentication.html#Digest) says:

> Digest authentication was added in the HTTP 1.1 protocol and while not
>   being as widely supported as Basic authentication there is a great
>   deal of support for it. Digest authentication is significantly more
>   secure than basic authentication as it never transfers the actual
>   password across the network, but instead uses it to encrypt a "nonce"
>   value sent from the server.

RFC 2617 explains it like this:

> nonce
>         A server-specified data string which should be uniquely generated
>         each time a 401 response is made.

And

> The nonce is opaque to the client.

What you probably want is a Cookie from the server. Once you're authenticated the server can issue a session cookie for you. So if you don't want to authenticate again, you need to [set that session cookie](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/cookies.html) that the server (usually) gives you after authentication, in your request which should do the trick.